# MS Excel: Get number of Rows where Fail condition is met in at least one Column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to get the number of users who have an invalid address. The address can be invalidated by an error in many different columns. I can retrieve the number of users with a error in a specific column with the function:

`{=SUM(IF('Sheet1'!N:N="FAIL", 1, 0))}` returns `4897`

However, I need to return the number of users with an error in any column. I have created the following function but it only returns `1`.

`{=SUM(IF(OR('Sheet1'!N:N="FAIL", 'Sheet1'!R:R="FAIL", 'Sheet1'!P:P="FAIL"), 1, 0))}` returns `1`

How do I correct the behavior of this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array Formulas do not like the use of `OR`.  One just needs to add the Boolean tests to mimic `OR`.

SUMPRODUCT, though still an array type formula does not need the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(('Sheet1'!N:N="FAIL")+('Sheet1'!R:R="FAIL")+('Sheet1'!P:P="FAIL")>0))
```